# Where do I find anaconda 3.6

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, downgrade

**I want to downgrade my anaconda**
I have anaconda installed in my local machine and the installed version is 4.8.0 when i checked in anaconda prompt, but i want to install anaconda version 3.6, iv'e tried anaconda website and found anaconda archive but unable to find anaconda 3.6 can anyone guide me with the solution? On anaconda 3.6 does exist?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't - and never was - Anaconda 3.6 (all thanks to somewhat weird numbering they're using). I guess what you mean is Anaconda with Python 3.6.

Two tips first:

- There's rarely a good reason to stick with an obsolete Anaconda version.
- Create new environment rather than modify the default environment (unless that's really what you want).

To create a new environment named `py36` with Python 3.6:

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6
```

To install Python 3.6 to the default:

```
conda install python=3.6
```